# Spring Boot, Vue.js and npm watch

Tags: spring-boot, npm, vuejs2

I have a stack containing Spring-Boot and Vue.js. By maven configuration project is separated into two modules: frontend and backend. During the **mvn clean install** plugin **exec-maven-plugin** build frontend part. On the backend side, plugin **maven-resources-plugin** copies frontend build into aprropriate directory. Finally, the jar with spring-boot and frontend side is created.

The problem is, that this configuration is completeally unconvinient for development process:

1. I am running spring-boot application under intellij.
2. I am running **"watch": "vue-cli-service build --watch",**
3. When change on the frontend side occures, frontend build is done and **./frontend/target/dist** directory is changed.
4. I manually copy **./frontend/target/dist** into **./backend/target/META-INF/.....**
5. Frontend changes are visible after page is reloaded.

The question is: is it possible to change target directory for frontend build process?

Comment: vue cli let you define the `outputDir` in `vue.config.js` to change the output directory of your build. However, I am not sure why you use maven to handle your frontend. May be you should use tools dedicated to frontend world (npm, vue-cli).

Comment: I think the best solution is to use `vue-cli-service serve` and configure proxy for api requests to spring backend

Comment: does it reload after changes with serve?